# Fopen isn't creating a new file

Tags: php, fopen

I know it's a repeated question , but I've tried everything .

So here's my code :

```
<?php
  $link = $_GET['link'];
  $urlparse = parse_url($link);
  $filename = $urlparse['host'] . ".txt";
  $dlink = "../get/" . $filename;
  if(isset($link)){
    $source = file_get_contents($link);
    $file = fopen($dlink,"w");
    $string = htmlspecialchars($source);
    fwrite($string,$file);
    fclose($file);
    chmod($dlink,0777);
  }
?>
```

** I removed some unnecessary parts of the code

Also , I've checked the allow fopen in the php.ini , I've checked the php file permission .
What happens is that the code runs with no warnings or errors , but , it doesn't create a new text file .

Comment: Check to make sure your file path is correct.

Comment: The code is wrong on so many levels -- for a start, `isset($link)` will always be true, since you set it in the first line (empty string is a value too!). You are not checking for permissions, or if the file was indeed opened (depending on PHP settings you may not get errors/warnings for any of the above). Perform all of these, and you will see the relevant error.

Comment: According to the docs tphp will attempt to create it. Check your permissions on the dir you want the file in.

Comment: You should be aware that one can read any file on your system with this script, e. g. `?link=file://localhost/etc/passwd`.

Comment: I've changed folder permission to 0777, still not working . And I'm not really paying attention to security holes right now because the code isn't meant to be published , it's only made to test the php file functions function so please ignore all security gapes and focus on what's important to me right now . Thanks ! :) anything else should I check ? I'll try error_reporting and show you what I get

Comment: Still not working ...

Answer (score 0):

Well, if fwrite doesn't throws any errors and no file is created, almost with all certainty you have "misconfigured" the error_reporting directive in php.ini:

Try with this and you should start getting your warnings and errors:

```
error_reporting = E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE
```